# Exception loading second time uiviewcontroller

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I hope you can help me out.

I am developing an iOS Xamarin app and I have a UIViewController with a tableView and from one row I load a other UIViewController. First time, it is working perfectly, it loads the next UIViewController without troubles, but then I go back from the navigation controller back button (automatic one) and when I try to open again the same row and load again the same UIViewController then it throws an exception that I am not able to debug, it just stops and breaks but does not stop in any line from my code. Seems to be something internal. 
Perhaps I don't want a solution because it will probably a specific thing from my project but at least I need to learn how debug these kind of errors because it is really tough to follow up.
I paste the complete trace below:

```
2017-02-08 15:22:39.896 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] Unhandled managed exception:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: view1 (System.ArgumentNullException)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3988/e02d2723/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3988/e02d2723/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at WorkFormGo.Felix.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in D:\Repository\Felixx\Produkte\Workform\Solutions\WorkFormGo\WorkFormGo.Felix\WorkFormGo.Felix.iOS\Main.cs:17 
2017-02-08 15:22:39.896 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical: Stacktrace:
2017-02-08 15:22:39.896 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical: 
Native stacktrace:
2017-02-08 15:22:39.979 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  0   WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x0010224d mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 317
2017-02-08 15:22:39.979 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  1   WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x0010b9b1 sigabrt_signal_handler + 161
2017-02-08 15:22:39.979 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x04e8479b _sigtramp + 43
2017-02-08 15:22:39.980 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
2017-02-08 15:22:39.980 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x04bfa11f abort + 141
2017-02-08 15:22:39.980 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  5   WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x002a38e0 _ZL20print_all_exceptionsP10MonoObject + 0
2017-02-08 15:22:39.980 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  6   WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x00102b60 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 96
2017-02-08 15:22:39.981 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  7   WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x0010192b mono_handle_exception_internal + 5611
2017-02-08 15:22:39.981 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  8   WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x00100339 mono_handle_exception + 41
2017-02-08 15:22:39.981 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  9   WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x000990a6 mono_x86_throw_exception + 182
2017-02-08 15:22:39.982 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  10  ???                                 0x0f427b57 0x0 + 256015191
2017-02-08 15:22:39.982 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  11  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x002a9c4c xamarin_invoke_trampoline + 8892
2017-02-08 15:22:39.982 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  12  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x002b0c6c xamarin_arch_trampoline + 156
2017-02-08 15:22:39.983 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  13  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x002b1346 xamarin_i386_common_trampoline + 36
2017-02-08 15:22:39.983 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  14  UIKit                               0x01462d83 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 168
2017-02-08 15:22:39.983 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  15  UIKit                               0x014631a6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 821
2017-02-08 15:22:39.983 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  16  UIKit                               0x01463451 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _recursiveUpdateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 139
2017-02-08 15:22:39.984 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  17  UIKit                               0x01463104 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 659
2017-02-08 15:22:39.984 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  18  UIKit                               0x01463451 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _recursiveUpdateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 139
2017-02-08 15:22:39.985 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  19  UIKit                               0x01463104 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 659
2017-02-08 15:22:39.985 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  20  UIKit                               0x01463451 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _recursiveUpdateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 139
2017-02-08 15:22:39.985 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  21  UIKit                               0x01463104 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 659
2017-02-08 15:22:39.985 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  22  UIKit                               0x01463451 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _recursiveUpdateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 139
2017-02-08 15:22:39.986 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  23  UIKit                               0x01463104 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 659
2017-02-08 15:22:39.986 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  24  UIKit                               0x01463451 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _recursiveUpdateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 139
2017-02-08 15:22:39.986 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  25  UIKit                               0x01463104 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 659
2017-02-08 15:22:39.987 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  26  UIKit                               0x01463afc __97-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededPostponeVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke_2 + 34
2017-02-08 15:22:39.987 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  27  Foundation                          0x00510122 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 152
2017-02-08 15:22:39.987 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  28  Foundation                          0x00510085 -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 31
2017-02-08 15:22:39.988 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  29  UIKit                               0x01462826 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 54
2017-02-08 15:22:39.988 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  30  UIKit                               0x01463ad4 __97-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededPostponeVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 88
2017-02-08 15:22:39.988 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  31  UIKit                               0x014628b7 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 129
2017-02-08 15:22:39.988 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  32  UIKit                               0x014635aa -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededPostponeVariableChangeNotifications:] + 185
2017-02-08 15:22:39.989 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  33  UIKit                               0x01464802 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededPostponeVariableChangeNotifications:] + 463
2017-02-08 15:22:39.989 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  34  UIKit                               0x01464cd7 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 31
2017-02-08 15:22:39.989 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  35  UIKit                               0x00a745ff -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 169
2017-02-08 15:22:39.990 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  36  UIKit                               0x00a74fed -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] + 573
2017-02-08 15:22:39.990 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  37  UIKit                               0x00dec8c7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 273
2017-02-08 15:22:39.990 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  38  UIKit                               0x00a87374 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1457
2017-02-08 15:22:39.992 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  39  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03da61b9 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 59
2017-02-08 15:22:39.992 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  40  QuartzCore                          0x028d374d -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 141
2017-02-08 15:22:39.992 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  41  QuartzCore                          0x028c6a2b _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
2017-02-08 15:22:39.993 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  42  QuartzCore                          0x028c6881 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 21
2017-02-08 15:22:39.993 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  43  QuartzCore                          0x028504c7 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 339
2017-02-08 15:22:39.993 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  44  QuartzCore                          0x0287f2b8 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 498
2017-02-08 15:22:39.993 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  45  QuartzCore                          0x02880dc8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17flush_transactionEv + 38
2017-02-08 15:22:39.994 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  46  UIKit                               0x009e144c _afterCACommitHandler + 375
2017-02-08 15:22:39.994 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  47  CoreFoundation                      0x0383676e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
2017-02-08 15:22:39.994 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  48  CoreFoundation                      0x038366c7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
2017-02-08 15:22:39.995 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  49  CoreFoundation                      0x0381a3a6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1414
2017-02-08 15:22:39.995 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  50  CoreFoundation                      0x03819bab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 395
2017-02-08 15:22:39.995 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  51  CoreFoundation                      0x03819a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
2017-02-08 15:22:39.995 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  52  GraphicsServices                    0x059bfb4c GSEventRunModal + 177
2017-02-08 15:22:39.996 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  53  GraphicsServices                    0x059bf9c7 GSEventRun + 80
2017-02-08 15:22:39.996 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  54  UIKit                               0x009b232b UIApplicationMain + 148
2017-02-08 15:22:39.996 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  55  ???                                 0x100dab64 0x0 + 269331300
2017-02-08 15:22:39.997 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  56  ???                                 0x100da914 0x0 + 269330708
2017-02-08 15:22:39.997 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  57  ???                                 0x100d8510 0x0 + 269321488
2017-02-08 15:22:39.997 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  58  ???                                 0x100d8188 0x0 + 269320584
2017-02-08 15:22:39.997 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  59  ???                                 0x100d838f 0x0 + 269321103
2017-02-08 15:22:39.998 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  60  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x001122f2 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1458
2017-02-08 15:22:39.998 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  61  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x001d2e4d do_runtime_invoke + 93
2017-02-08 15:22:39.998 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  62  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x001d51fd mono_runtime_exec_main + 1005
2017-02-08 15:22:39.999 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  63  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x001d4d3c mono_runtime_run_main + 876
2017-02-08 15:22:39.999 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  64  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x00098809 mono_jit_exec + 265
2017-02-08 15:22:39.999 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  65  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x002b00a9 xamarin_main + 3433
2017-02-08 15:22:39.999 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  66  WorkFormGoFelixiOS                  0x002b18c1 main + 113
2017-02-08 15:22:40.000 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:  67  libdyld.dylib                       0x04b54799 start + 1
2017-02-08 15:22:40.000 WorkFormGoFelixiOS[5150:4809781] critical:
```

I can't find out what view1 is... It is nothing to do with the views I have in my code. No one is called like this...
Btw, I am developing with Xamarin on Visual Studio and I updated everything today to the latest version.

Thank you guys!

Comment: please post the relevant portions of your code

Comment: Another way to figure out what is going on is to break when you get the exception. Open up exception settings and set it to break on ArgumentNullException.